# Changing Inline CSS with no id or class with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

well I am trying to **remove a add** from this site **[anisp.gq](http://anisp.gq) put by the hosting provider**...  its a practice site just for fun ...

The server on which the site is hosted puts this add on it after all the code and I have **no access to this last bit of code on the admin-panel side**:

```
<!-- Actual Website Code Above^^^ --> 
<!-- Last bit of add code that I want to remove ↓↓ -->

<div style="text-align:right;position:fixed;bottom:3px;right:3px;width:100%;z-index:999999;cursor:pointer;line-height:0;display:block;">

    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.freewebhostingarea.com" title="Free Web Hosting with PHP5 or PHP7">

    <img alt="Free Web Hosting" src="https://www.freewebhostingarea.com/images/poweredby.png" style="border-width: 0px;" width="180" height="45">

    </a>
    </div>
```

Hence, I have no access to this last bit of code I decided to use JavaScript to get the inline display tag to change but due to there being no id or class present I am struggling ...

I have been trying to get the style tags **display attribute to change to none in this div section ...**

But as you can see there is no id and class tag there so

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none";
```

is out of question in my view ...

I have been trying you can say stupid stuff like this :

```
var node = document.querySelector('[style="text-align:right;position:fixed;bottom:3px;right:3px;width:100%;z-index:999999;cursor:pointer;line-height:0;display:block;"]').display="none";
```

/*and the below one */

```
 var node = document.querySelector('[style="text-align:right;position:fixed;bottom:3px;right:3px;width:100%;z-index:999999;cursor:pointer;line-height:0;display:block;"]');

document.getElementById("node").style.display ="none";
```

and some other stuff but nothing works and my lack of knowledge with DOM and JS is not helping either .... so I have no idea what I am doing is right wrong or what ... Please tell me whats the right approach ...

Thanks for Your Time

Comment: Be aware that the user policy of using that (free) space may require that the advertisement is shown.

Comment: I don't care about that as soon as something concrete happens ... I will shift to a more robust hosting provider ... But I need to remove that add for now ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could target the child `<a>` tag and then jump up to the parent.

```
var node = document.querySelector(
  'a[href="https://www.freewebhostingarea.com"]'
).parentNode;

node.style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: Umm... I am new to JS can you please give detail to how I can edit the parent node after getting it ...  I was thinking of using this approach  (parentNode.style.display = "none";) is it correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Both of your attempts almost works, there's just a small issue in both.
For the first one, you are missing `style` before display.

```js
var node = document.querySelector('[style="text-align:right;position:fixed;bottom:3px;right:3px;width:100%;z-index:999999;cursor:pointer;line-height:0;display:block;"]').style.display = "none";
```

```html
<div style="text-align:right;position:fixed;bottom:3px;right:3px;width:100%;z-index:999999;cursor:pointer;line-height:0;display:block;">

  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.freewebhostingarea.com" title="Free Web Hosting with PHP5 or PHP7">

    <img alt="Free Web Hosting" src="https://www.freewebhostingarea.com/images/poweredby.png" style="border-width: 0px;" width="180" height="45">

  </a>
</div>
```

In the latter attempt you are not using the value that you assign to your `node` variable. Should be like this:

```js
 var node = document.querySelector('[style="text-align:right;position:fixed;bottom:3px;right:3px;width:100%;z-index:999999;cursor:pointer;line-height:0;display:block;"]');

node.style.display = "none";
```

```html
<div style="text-align:right;position:fixed;bottom:3px;right:3px;width:100%;z-index:999999;cursor:pointer;line-height:0;display:block;">

  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.freewebhostingarea.com" title="Free Web Hosting with PHP5 or PHP7">

    <img alt="Free Web Hosting" src="https://www.freewebhostingarea.com/images/poweredby.png" style="border-width: 0px;" width="180" height="45">

  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Well none of them worked for me due to some unknown reason .... Sometimes the page just keeps on loading and loading but doesn't load fully ... but when I remove the scripts it works just fine ... I don't know why this happens ... any ideas ? The css one above works fine somehow though ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want a non-javascript solution, this CSS will do.

```
div[style="text-align:right;position:fixed;bottom:3px;right:3px;width:100%;z-index:999999;cursor:pointer;line-height:0;display:block;"] {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Not JS that I was trying to use and do .. But this one works thanks